# Qt Creator: QTabWidget: I can't remove a tab

Tags: tabs, qtabwidget

Sorry for my English. I'm new to Qt, in my project the user can move from one tab to the next one. ( Slot of the button: ui->Pestanas->insertTab(1, ui->Pestana_Orden_Trabajo, "Orden de Trabajo");
ui->Pestanas->setCurrentIndex(1); )

It works, but I would like to just show the first tab when the window appears for the first time.
I've tried this:

```
Partes::Partes(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Partes)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->Pestanas->setCurrentIndex(0);
    ui->Pestanas->removeTab(1);
    ui->Pestanas->removeTab(2);

}
```

It makes disappear the second tab that comes with the QTabWidget deffault form when you first include it in the ui. But the the tab that I added for designing the widgets I want it to bring inside doesn't disappear.

Does anyone know any way to do it?

Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 3):

Solved. 
The problem was that when it does the first remove the indexes change, so when I remove index 1 indexes go from being 0,1,2 to be 0,1. The second remove tries to remove index 2 that stopped existing when I did the first remove.
So the solution is:

```
Partes::Partes(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Partes)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->Pestanas->setCurrentIndex(0);
    ui->Pestanas->removeTab(1);
    ui->Pestanas->removeTab(1);

}
```

Or:

```
Partes::Partes(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Partes)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->Pestanas->setCurrentIndex(0);
    ui->Pestanas->removeTab(2);
    ui->Pestanas->removeTab(1);

}
```

How can I mark this post as solved?

Comment: Give yourself best answer